# How to set backgroundColor of a ViewController with UIAppearance

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiappearance, uibackgroundcolor

I'm trying to use UIAppearance to configure the style of my Apps. It works perfectly with the UI components like UIView or UIButton, but it doesn't with UIViewControllers. I would like to do something like:

```
let appearance = FirstViewController.appearance()
```

Is there a way to use UIAppearance with ViewControllers?

Comment: may you need view controller view , just a guess.

Comment: `UIViewController` does not have an `appearnace()`

Comment: UIViewcontroller not extend the UIAppearnce class that's way you can't use it. UIView is extend the UIAppearnce class.

Comment: I think you're confusing `UIViewController` with `UIView`. While `UIView` is likely too much a "base class" for your intentions, maybe you could (1) subclass `UIView`, (2) set your `UIViewController` view to be that subclass, and (3) configure `UIAppearence` for that.

Comment: Hi @dfd, can I assign a custom UIView as a default view for a UIViewController?

Comment: Sure. The syntax is `self.view = myCustomView`.

Comment: I tried... but then all @IBOutlets turns nil. Have I to override the loadView() func?

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance) of the `UIAppearance` protocol, only two classes adopt it by default, `UIView` and `UIBarItem`, hence the `UIViewController` class has no `appearance()` function.

You can either extend `UIViewController` by implementing the required methods of the protocol, or probably an even easier solution would be to create your own `UIViewController` subclass, which provides a default color for the classes `view.backgroundColor` property and make all your ViewControllers inherit from this class instead of `UIViewController` directly.

Answer (score 3):

You don´t set the background color in a `viewController` you do set it on the `viewControllers` `view`. If you use `UIView.appearance().backgroundColor` you will change the background of all views.

So the answer to your question is no you can´t use `UIAppearance` to change the `viewControllers` background color.

What you could do is the following:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Then use the inspector in your Storyboard to change `UIViewController` to `FirstViewController`.

Comment: Won't this affect ALL views, not just view controller views?

Comment: @rmaddy, I was not clear enough, thought it was obvious but has clarified the answer now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @rmaddy this only affect the view controllers which, in Storyboard inspector, has its class assigned to `FirstViewController` or subclass of `FirstViewController`.

One of the usage is to extend the default `UINavigationController` and set the background to white.  So the top right corner will not display a flash of dark grey color.

Comment: @John My comment applies to the original answer, not the current one.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers have pointed out, there's no way to change `UIViewController`'s root view background through `UIAppearance` protocol. 
But there are ways to achieve the same result without the need to have a root `UIViewController` subclass inherited by all other `ViewControllers`, or setting the color in every `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` (both approaches have their drawbacks)

Instead you can create a UIView subclass

```
class BackgroundView: UIView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Set your background color
        self.backgroundColor = .black

        // Or, if your background is an image
        self.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "background")!.cgImage
    }
}
```

In the storyboard, set your `ViewController`'s root view class to this UIView subclass
[image: screenshot]

And the same approach works for `UITableViewController`

```
class BackgroundTableView: UITableView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
[....]
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]